# Watson et al: Beginning Visual C# Chapter 10 exercise 5

Tags: c#

The question is for anyone who has referred to the solution provided for this question at the end of the book.
I have set up Ch10CardLib as outlined at the end of the chapter. Running the included client console application displaying a shuffled deck is no problem.

I have run the solution provided to obtain an error message on the following line:

```
Suit flushSuit = playDeck.GetCard(hand * 5).suit;
```

> "Error    1   'Ch10CardLib.Card' does not contain a definition for 'suit' and no extension method 'suit' accepting a first argument of type 'Ch10CardLib.Card' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

"Suit" is an enum type, but "suit" is a private readonly field in the Card class.

Can anyone divine the author's intention here?

Just for "fun" I decided to include a method in the Card class:

```
public Suit Suit()
{
    return suit;
}

Suit flushSuit = playDeck.GetCard(hand * 5).Suit();
```

This produces the desired result, but is it in the spirit of the context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a syntax error. If the code in the book doesn't compile (I don't have a copy of the book), then it's not your fault. Your fix looks perfectly reasonable to me, although I would probably have exposed it as a readonly property rather than a method:

```
public Suit Suit
{
    get { return suit; }
}
```

Perhaps you could swap the private readonly field for an auto property?

```
public Suit Suit { get; private set; }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a much better idea. Strange that this text was recommended by Microsoft, but not used as a University text, or it surely would have been picked up before...